# how do i copy or assign custom or multiple values to tfs work item field?

Tags: tfs

How do you assign multiple values to a work item field?

I am trying to prepend a fixed string onto a work item title, specifically a task work item.
I want to change the prepend string based upon another field and apply it to the title

For example when the activity filed is deployment

I want to prepend " BLD" to the title , so it the tile was "abcd" I want it to be "BLD:abcd"

Comment: I can detect the value of the acitivity field with a <WHEN> condition , I am not sure how to reassign the title

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do it with field rules.  You're probably looking at a server side event handler that detects the Activity field change and prefixes the appropriate code to the title.